# b2cAuthenticationMethodsPolicy method's permissions not sufficient

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am following this documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/api/b2cauthenticationmethodspolicy-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

but even when I give my service principal the policy.read.all graph api permission, I still get 403 permission denied errors as response to my request. I have the same issue with the PATCH request and the    Policy.ReadWrite.AuthenticationMethod.

Note : the bearer is correct, I can use it to make other requests.

I also found a log of the request in the azure ad saying :

```
Access denied. The token is app only but does not have any valid permissions.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error message, you may not be a logged-in user, you need a logged-in user to call the api. Please follow my process:

1. First you need to grant the **Policy.Read.All** permission to the application, and then make the **admin consent** to the permission.

[image]

2. Next, you need to use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain the access token, which requires you to log in to the user to obtain the authorization code, and then use the authorization code to redeem the access token.

[image]

3.Call ms graph api:

[image]

In addition, calling the api also requires the user to have an administrator role:

> You must have one of the following user roles for access: External ID
> User Flow Administrator, External ID User Flow Attribute
> Administrator, External Identity Provider Administrator, Application
> Administrator, Security Administrator, Security Reader, Global Reader,
> Global Administrator.

Comment: it's working ! thank you very much Carl. Can you provide me with some explaination ? 

Mainly I'd like to understand the difference between logging in as a user with the code like you showed me and the normal login with the grant_type=client_credentials ? Does the code mode logs you in as a user and the client_credentials as an application ?

Also is there a reason for this particular request to ask us to provide a permission code ? I use a lot of other requests on the graph API and the client_credentials grant_type was always enough.

Comment: @GOT  Of course, auth code flow and client_credentials flow the most essential difference is whether there is a user login. client_credentials flow is a daemon-based application, this type of grant is commonly used for server-to-server interactions that must run in the background, without immediate interaction with a user(no user logged in).  The auth code flow requires you to log in as a user. It does not use `client_credentials` as an application login, it uses `authorization_code`.

Comment: As for your second question: `I use a lot of other requests on the graph API and the client_credentials grant_type was always enough`. This is related to the api you requested. Different apis have different authorization requirements. In the current problem, because calling the api requires administrator permissions, you must log in as a user, so you need to use the auth code flow. After authentication, your token will carry user information, and the api will determine whether you have permission to call it by verifying the role of the user in the token.

Comment: That's very clear. Thank you for your time Carl :)

Comment: I'm sorry but is there any way to get that code without having to login inside a browser ? I'm actualy scripting a whole process and it's in the middle of it. If I try to get the code from the flow it's obviously not redirecting to the code because I don't have a user logged in and of course if I set the prompt parameter to "none" I get a permission denied kind of error.